# PHP ultimate security

Tags: php, sql, security

Im working in web application, i finished the template design and HTML/CSS integration.Now i'm facing a new chalenge is to start developing the solution using PHP/Oracle 10g and other Web technologies.

My questions are :

1. What is the best and secure way to connect to a database using PHP?
2. Where i have to store the username and password the oracle scheme (to be more secure)
3. For developers with (PHP/Oracle) experience , what do you use as a class to connect to the database ?

(This is my first php application)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to connect to a database with PHP (assuming you're not using a framework) would be to install the PDO module (if not installed already). There's a good article on why you should do this and how to do it here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

The PDO module provides some level of security by using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). This protects you against [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Additionally, the PDO module contains a number of drivers which will allow your application to connect to a number of databases, including Oracle (although through an additional extension) http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php.

Comment: thank you for your rich answer, i may need an additional information, where i have to store the username/password of the database? (in separate file or use it directely in my connection class ?)

Comment: The answer to your question is it's up to you. Normally the username and password would be stored as a variable in your PHP code. They would then be used whenever you made a connection to the database using something like this `$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);`. In this example I have used MySQL not Oracle but the `$host`, `$dbname`, `$user`, and `$pass` are all variables defined somewhere else. Where you store them is up to you.

Comment: Ok i see now, and there is any problem of security when we use it as that way ?

Comment: Not really. As long as no one can access your code then they can't read the details.

Comment: Ok thank you, then it's about server security (the server should be secured and not let foreigner get in access). clair now